# how create multiple shapes of button in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-button

I Want to create multiples shapes of button like heart,polygon,star..
and button look and feel should be same as type of button.

any guideline will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shape drawable and set it as a background of your button

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

For achieving button press behaviour you need to create selector drawable and set it as a background of button Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">         
<item android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/start_pressed_state.png"/>         
<item android:drawable="@drawable/start_unpressed_state.png"/>
```

Comment: thanks but just we usually have square  round rectangle button by default but what if i want it look to as as that type of image for example i set background image to be a star then but  should look like a star no extra padding in that button and when i press that it should feel like i press star